# Is there a way to compare array with array using switch case in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I already tried to compare array with array with using if like this:

```
let ArrayA = ["A", "B"]

if ArrayA == ["A", "B"] {
   print("true")
} else {
   print("false")
}
```

And the result will be `true`, then how we do it with switch and case ? Is that possible to do it with Swift language ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cases with `where` predicates:

```
let array = ["A", "B"]

switch array {
    case _ where array == ["A", "B"]: print("AB")
    case _ where array == ["C", "D"]: print("CD")
    default: print("default")
}
```

If you really wanted, you could define a pattern match operator (`~=`) that calls `==`. The `switch` statement looks for definitions of the pattern match operator that accept the given pattern and candidate to determine whether a `case` is matched:

```
let array = ["A", "B"]

func ~= <T: Equatable>(pattern: [T], candidate: [T]) -> Bool {
    return pattern == candidate
}

switch array {
    case ["A", "B"]: print("AB")
    case ["C", "D"]: print("CD")
    default: print("default")
}
```

I would ***advise against this***, however, because it's not clear whether such a case is doing a `==` check, `contains(_:)`, `hasPrefix(_:)`, etc.

Comment: Where does the "func ~=...." code goes? Should it be declared inside an extension of Array type? or it just goes "anywhere" and within that code i should check if it's of [String] type? Would you mind posting a working example?

Comment: @Pochi I posted two working examples... The `~=` function could be a static member in an extension on Array, or as a standalone function in the global scope

Comment: Ah i see, yeah i just tried it on playgrounds. The thing i don't understand is how does the "func (~=) " knows its scope. Like, once I declare this in any of my files, it will affect all switch comparisons? Wouldn't this affect other types? Would declaring it as a static member within an array extension make it safer? (Sorry i've just never seen this pattern matching thing before)

Comment: @Pochi The scope of the `~=` works like any other function. It's `internal` by default, but you could make it `public`, or `fileprivate`. It only effects `switch` statements found in places that have access to it. E.g. if it was `internal` (the default), then all `switch` statements across your module would use it.

Comment: @Pochi Why add it to an extension? What did you try? I just tried it, works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149063/discussion-between-alexander-and-pochi).

Answer (score 2):

Switch in Swift work with many different types but it just doesn’t match arrays out of the box. You can match arrays by overloading the ~= appropriately

```
func ~=<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}

let ArrayA = ["A","B"]
switch ArrayA {
case (["A","B"]):
   print("true")
default:
   print("false")
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this existed... lol. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371870/operator-in-swift