# pattern matching for strings

Tags: swift, string, pattern-matching

```
func swtiching (a: String, b: String){
    switch (a,b){
    case ("a", "b"): print("a and b")
    case (("a" || "c"), ("b" || "d")): print(" a or b and c or d")

    default: print("something else")
    }
}
```

If I do this, the 2nd case will give the following error:

> cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type
>   'Bool'

**EDIT:**

```
if "a" == "a" || "c"{
print("xyz")
}
```

This would also result in the same error.

Comment: You mean `if a == "a" || a == "c" {`

Comment: yes, but I want to avoid doing that.

Comment: I had a problem understanding the error, that is the `||` operator **only** works for two `Bool`s. I was then thinking about overloading `||`, so it would accept two `String`s but then would I expect the result to be?! (With 2 Bools, you end up with 1 Bool, same isn't true for 2 strings) A tuple String? OK! But then I guess I would have to overload the something else which I'm not sure of so I'd be able to *compare* a `String` against a `tuple` of Strings?

Comment: You can also do `if ["a", "c"].contains(a) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would cook up:

```
struct DisjunctiveMatcher<T: Equatable> {
    let desired: [T]
    func matches(candidate: T) -> Bool { return desired.contains(candidate) }
}

func ~= <T: Equatable>(pattern: DisjunctiveMatcher<T>, candidate: T) -> Bool {
    return pattern.matches(candidate: candidate)
}

func oneOf<T: Equatable>(_ elements: T...) -> DisjunctiveMatcher<T> {
    return DisjunctiveMatcher(desired: elements)
}


func swtichingExample(a: String, b: String) {
    switch (a, b) {
    case ("a", "b"): print("a and b")
    case (oneOf("a", "b"), oneOf("b", "d")): print(" a or b and c or d")

    default: print("something else")
    }
}
```

If you realllllly want to achieve exactly the syntax you want, that's possible too, but I **would strongly advise against it**, because such a overload of `||` is quite unintuitive, and deviates from what people would expect. I'm just pointing out that it's possible:

```
/// Starts a chain of strings, where lhs and rhs are used to
/// define a DisjunctiveMatcher<String>
func || (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> DisjunctiveMatcher<String> {
    return DisjunctiveMatcher(desired: [lhs, rhs])
}

/// Extends an existing chain of strings, where rhs is added
/// to the desired strings of las
func || (lhs: DisjunctiveMatcher<String>, rhs: String) -> DisjunctiveMatcher<String> {
    return DisjunctiveMatcher(desired: lhs.desired + [rhs])
}

func crazySwitchingExample(a: String, b: String) {
    switch (a, b) {
    case ("a", "b"): print("a and b")
    case (("a" || "c"), ("b" || "d")): print("Go home, you're drunk. ")

    default: print("something else")
    }
}
```

Comment: for anyone who was dumbfounded like me on where the `~=` is used...See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371870/operator-in-swift). Will reduce the pain

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is way a bit terse for me. I'm slowing getting a grip over it :/. I placed a `print(elements)` inside the `oneOf` function and placed a `print(desired)` inside the `DisjunctiveMatcher` struct, but I only see elements related to the first side printed ie the lhs, I don't see the rhs. See [this](https://imgur.com/a/1VfIt) image. Is this a bug?

Comment: @Honey Why would it check the b d case (and make a matcher for it), if it's already known that a c doesn't match?

Comment: facepalm! right. but still when I paste your code into IBM sandbox...it doesn't print if I give it (a:"a", b:"b") my prints...It only prints the end result from switchingExample... (my playground keeps crashing or doesn't run. It's been always buggy, so I won't count on that)

Answer (score 1):

Using tuple patterns, if you want to match all combinations of different combinations of `a` being one of "a" or "c" and `b` being one of "b" or "d", as far as I know, if you don't to overload the pattern matching operators (`~+`), your only solution would be explicitly writing out all possible tuples (`("a",b"),("a","d"),("c","b"),("c","d")`), which is quite cumbersome even for 2 values.

I think using `if` statements and creating an array with all possible values for the variables, then calling `[String].contains()` is an easier solution for this case.

```
func switching (a: String, b: String){
    if a == "a", b == "b" {
        print("a and b")
    } else if ["a","c"].contains(a), ["b","d"].contains(b) {
        print(" a or b and c or d")
    } else {
        print("something else")
    }
}

switching(a: "a", b: "b") // print("a and b")
switching(a: "a", b: "d") // print(" a or b and c or d")
```

Comment: "your only solution would be explicitly writing out all possible tuples" nope, you can define pattern matching operators (`~=`) to define the matching behaviour you want

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the input, I didn't realize that was possible (hence the "as far as I know" part, which you didn't quote), but updated my answer.

Comment: No problem :) It's pretty nifty, actually

Comment: Your answer is very clever...I'm sorry I couldn't 2 answers as accepted.