# Swift - Group values of Int keys by multiple Int ranges

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, grouping

I want to group a list of employees by their id and find out how many fall into a specific range.

**For example:**
Suppose we have 3 ranges for ids:
[1, 10]
[12, 23]
[25, 33]

And we have 5 employees:
Steve, id 1
Peter, id 3
Paul, id 12
Mary, id 28
John, id 18

*The result should show:*
**Steve & Peter** get assigned to the range **[1, 10]** because their ids are within that range.
**Paul & John** get assigned to the range **[12, 23]** because their ids are within that range.
**Mary** gets assigned to the range **[25, 33]** because her id is within that range.

What is the best way to get this result in Swift?
My approach is to use a dictionary to first group by id and then in the next step map the ids to the ranges.
The first step is clear:

```
// Class Employee has the properties 'id' (Int) and 'name' (String)

let dict = Dictionary(grouping: employees) { // employees is of type [Employee]
   $0.id   // group by id
}
```

But here I'm stuck - I can't wrap my head around how to do the mapping correctly without looping through all combinations.

As result I would like to get:

```
[(5,6,[Steve, Peter]),
 (12,23,[Paul, John]),
 (25,33,[Mary]
]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're pretty close!

Let's make a couple of changes. First, since we're dealing with ranges, lets define them:

```
let ranges = [
    1...10,
    12...23,
    25...33
]
```

then we're going to group the employees (just like you did) but match them with a range:

```
let groups = Dictionary(grouping: employees) { e in
    ranges.first(where: { $0 ~= e.id })
}
```

Note here that I'm using the [pattern matching operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371870/operator-in-swift) `~=` but you could also use `$0.contains(e.id)`

And we're done. Here is an example of this:

```
struct Employee {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

let employees = [
    Employee(id:  1, name: "Steve"),
    Employee(id:  3, name: "Peter"),
    Employee(id: 12, name: "Paul"),
    Employee(id: 28, name: "Mary"),
    Employee(id: 18, name: "John")
]
```

gives an output of:

```
25...33 [Employee(id: 28, name: "Mary")]
12...23 [Employee(id: 12, name: "Paul"), Employee(id: 18, name: "John")]
1...10  [Employee(id: 1, name: "Steve"), Employee(id: 3, name: "Peter")]
```

where the keys are the ranges and the values are the matching employees.

Finally, there are obvious issues like what happens with range overlapping, but this is up to your program's logic to decide...