# I want write a code in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want write a 8-bit array in swift and I want get array`s value to Calculation   ex: >> 8 , & 255 
How can I write in swift?

I write this now

`var bytes:[UInt8] = [0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xff]
bytes[5]
bytes[5] = bytes[5] >> 8 （but here error）`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153003/3141234

Comment: By the way, while that duplicate shows ways to shift array by a certain number of bits, if you're going to shift by exactly eight bits, then it's easier, because you're effectively shift by one byte, i.e., insert new byte `0x0` at the start, and remove the last byte.