# how to rearrange cell in didselect method in iOS Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

Consider i have an array ["one","two","three","four","five"]. i want rearrange the cell in didselect method.

For example:

```
var items = [UserObject]()
```

Model:

```
 import SwiftyJSON

class UserObject {

var URL: String!
var Name: String!


  required init(json: JSON) {
    URL = json["URL"].stringValue
    Name = json["Name"].stringValue
  }
}
```

when tapping on cell two, then array should be ["two","three","four","five","one"]

when tapping on cell four, then array should be ["three","four","five","one","two"]

i tried like this and its working fine but i need another method

In didselect method

```
var data = self.items[0]
self.items.remove(at: 0)
self.items.insert(data, at: 4)
tableView.reloadData()
```

**Is there any alternative method to achieve this?**

how can i achieve this with tableview and wihtout tableview?

Comment: There is one property on tableView i.e. reloadData https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata. How you can achieve this is in `didSelectRow`. You will first update the model i.e. move the content of select index to to front of array and then call reload data.

Comment: @Rahul i have updated question, can you check it out..

Comment: it seems like you have to apply left bitwise operator on your array item until you reach your required value after that reload table view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a `cell/index` You're shifting the selected one to `index 0`,

You can implement this `extension` and use it whenever you need shifting :

```
extension Array {
    func shiftRight(_ amount: Int = 1) -> [Element] {
        var amount = amount
        assert(-count...count ~= amount, "Shift amount out of bounds")
        if amount < 0 { amount += count }  // this needs to be >= 0
        return Array(self[amount ..< count] + self[0 ..< amount])
    }

    mutating func shiftRightInPlace(amount: Int = 1) {
        self = shiftRight(amount)
    }
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299723/8192960)

Now for your  `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` you can use this easily in `didSelect` function .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
items = items.shiftRight(indexPath.row)
}
```

Last step is to add a property listener to your data source, so you can automatically refresh the `tableView` or the `collectionView` whenever it changes values like this

```
var items = ["one","two","three","four","five"] {
    didSet {
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Additionally to your case :

Change this: `var items = [UserObject]()`

To this:

```
var items: [UserObject] = [] {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where to use didSet in viewdidload?

Comment: No where you declare your data source

Comment: Nothing to do with didload look at my example its associated with the data source nothing to do with anything else , use it simply where you declare your data source array

Comment: its model var items = [UserObject]()

Comment: Yea change it to items: [UserOject] = [] then add the didSet to it

Comment: DidSet is an additional step you know you can just reload the table after shifting in didSelect function

Comment: it crashing UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only

Comment: it shouldn't crash but ill edit now for this warning, should be working fine  .

Comment: @ParameswaranV try this, should work look updated line

Comment: thanks now its not crashing. but rows are not changed items.shiftRight(indexPath.row) Result of call to 'shiftRight' is unused

Comment: oh yeah, change it to this, sorry `items = items.shiftRight(indexPath.row)`@ParameswaranV

Comment: its working now but when i click on first cell it does not changing the row. In selecting cell 2 and 3 it works fine

Comment: the first cell index is 0 .. its not going to shift anything .. you know in your question you said tapping 2,3,4... etc cells i mean if cell one on the top ... why do you rearrange ? the idea is shifting whatever you clicked on to the top .

Comment: @ParameswaranV kindly upvote accept answer, this is filling your requirements :) happy coding .

Comment: it should rearrange cell when tapping on any cell

Comment: @ParameswaranV just change the shifting function to any number you like, put a counter and increment it when you click

Comment: @MohmmadS this is basically left shift operator not right. just to clear function name should be shiftleft

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function.

```
//Pass index (selected cell index)
func arrangArray(ForIndex index: Int) {

    for i in 0..<self.items.count {

        if i == index {
            break
        }
        let user = self.items[0]
        self.items.remove(at: 0)
        self.items.append(user)
    }
} 
......

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    arrangArray(ForIndex: indexPath.row)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: it shows error Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[UserObject]'

Comment: in your code you mention string array. please provide proper details

Comment: replace [String] --> [UserObject]

Comment: it shows var arranged : [UserObject] = Array(items[index < items.count]) Cannot subscript a value of type '[UserObject]' with an index of type 'Bool'

Comment: Value of type '[UserObject]' has no member 'add'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199733/discussion-between-rohit-makwana-and-parameswaran-v).