# How do I perform a circular shift in Swift?

Tags: swift, binary

I am trying to perform a circular shift in Swift and I currently have the following code which uses a string containing the bits of the number I am trying to perform the circular shift on. Here is the code I have so far,

```
func circularRightShift(_ input: UInt8, _ amount: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
    guard amount > 0 else { return input }
    var a = String(UInt("\(input)")!, radix: 2)
    if a.count != 8 {
        a = "".padding(toLength: 8-a.count, withPad: "0", startingAt: 0) + a
    }
    for _ in 1...amount {
        a.insert(a.last!, at: a.startIndex)
        a.removeLast()
    }
    return UInt8(a, radix: 2)!
}
```

This code works properly, but it's a bit slow. Is there any better way to achieve this, possibly without using a string? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with two bit shift operators and a bitwise OR:

```
func circularRightShift(_ input: UInt8, _ amount: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
    let amount = amount % 8 // Reduce to the range 0...7
    return (input >> amount) | (input << (8 - amount))
}
```

Example (amount=5):

```
abcdefgh    <- bits of input

00000abc    <- bits of input >> amount
defgh000    <- bits of input << (8 - amount)
defghabc    <- bits of result
```

Answer (score 5):

Another, more general answer is this:

```swift
func circularShift<ShiftType: BinaryInteger>(_ first: ShiftType, by shiftAmount: Int) -> ShiftType {
    (first << shiftAmount) | (first >> (first.bitWidth - shiftAmount))
}
```

You can also create an extension:

```swift
extension BinaryInteger {
    func circularShifted(by shiftAmount: Int) -> Self {
        (self << shiftAmount) | (self >> (self.bitWidth - shiftAmount))
    }
}
```

To be even more flexible, you can take the sign of the operation into account and differentiate between left and right shifting:

```swift
extension BinaryInteger where Self: UnsignedInteger {
    func rotateLeft(by shiftAmount: Int) -> Self {
        if shiftAmount < 0 {
            return rotateRight(by: -shiftAmount)
        }
        return (self << shiftAmount) | (self >> (self.bitWidth - shiftAmount))
    }
    
    func rotateRight(by shiftAmount: Int) -> Self {
        if shiftAmount < 0 {
            return rotateLeft(by: -shiftAmount)
        }
        return (self >> shiftAmount) | (self << (self.bitWidth - shiftAmount))
    }
}
```

which can then be used like

```
let x: UInt8 = 0xE
String(x.rotateLeft(by: 2), radix: 16) // 3A
String(x.rotateRight(by: 2), radix: 16) // A3
```

Comment: 0x66 and 0x99 are both binary palindromes, so they are not great test data for ROR and ROL operations. 0x66 ROR by 2 bits is the same as 0x66 ROL by 2 bits.

Comment: `precondition()` crashes the app if the condition is false, right? That seems like an overreaction to trying to do a bitwise rotation on a negative number. How about returning an Optional containing nil if the value is negative?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the name `rotate(by:)`, because the fact that "positive shift amount means left" isn't very clear. It's conventional, but not very clear. I think just having `rotateLeft(by:)` and `rotateRight(by:)` would be more clear at the call site.

Comment: It also seems to be like `rotateLeft(by: anAmountThatCanBeNegative)` seems pretty clear/well-defined. I would recommend just making `rotateRight(by: amount)` just call `rotateLeft(by: -amount)`. See this array shifting code for comparison https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153003/3141234

Comment: I would suggest to restrict the method to *unsigned* integers. Right-shifting signed integers replicates leading (sign) bit, which leads to unexpected results.

Comment: I agree with the criticism but like Alexander's answer the most. I will update the post accordingly

Comment: In the line following `if shiftAmount < 0 {` there needs to be a `return` before `rotateRight(by: ...` and likewise in the second function.  That aside, nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to shift your number as 16-bits, and then combine the two bytes with each other, like this:

```
func circular(n: UInt8, k: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
    var s = UInt16(n) << (k & 0x07)
    return UInt8(s & 0xFF) | UInt8(s >> 8)
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/iZH0PQ)